# Mips branch: testing equality

Tags: branch, hardware, mips, cpu-registers

I need to know how can I test the equality of two registers in MIPS without using branches?
I need to make a new instruction that does the same as the beq without using branches...
The Labeling part can be done easily by using the Jump instruction, but how can we check for equality ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

If you've got two numbers `X` and `Y`, and `X - Y` equals 0, then `X` and `Y` are equal.

So, for example, if the two values you want to compare are in `$t0` and `$t1`:

```
# $t2 will be 0 if $t0 and $t1 are equal, and non-zero otherwise
subu $t2, $t0, $t1
```

If you want to normalize the result to either 0 (non-equal) or 1 (equal), you could expand the above with:

```
# Set $t2 to 1 if it's non-zero
sltu $t2, $zero, $t2
# Flip the lsb so that 0 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 0
xori $t2, $t2, 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now we got that t2 is 1 if they are equal, however how can we perform the jump now? my plan was from the beginning to do a branch, if t0 and t1 are equal, i should jump, else i should proceed without jumping...

Comment: What's this for in the end? That is, in what specific situation are you planning to use this? As a generic replacement for `BEQ` it's a really bad idea (I'll just point out the fact that there's a `JR` instruction that jumps to the address contained in a register). If there's a specific case that you'd like to implement in a branchless way then that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to avoid using slt/slti/sltu/sltui you will have to resort to bit-by-bit manipulation of instructions, using J-format most probably.

Otherwise computing the difference then doing sltu $(result), $0, $(difference) is the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the first register isn't smaller than the second, and the second isn't smaller than the first, so it means they are equals...

```
  slt $t0 $t1 $t2    #t0 is 0 if t1==t2 or t1>t2
  slt $t0 $t2 $t1    #t0 is 0 if t1==t2 or t1<t2
```

so if $t0 has value 0, then they are equal else they are unequal